# Trying to make the Android Navigation Bar transparent in Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm working on a React Native project with expo and am trying to have the Android Navigation bar rest on top of my view (as shown below and described [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge))

[image: transparent navigation bar]

However I am having difficulty getting my desired result instead I get a gray bar at the bottom.

[image: unsuccessful transparent navigation bar]

Thus far I've tried to set the navigation bar to transparent in my [app.json](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#backgroundcolor-2) file or use [NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync(color)](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#backgroundcolor-2) both ending with the same result.

```
//app.json
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "backgroundColor":"#00000000"
    },
```

```
//App.js
    //also tried flex: 1
    <View style={{height: Dimensions.get("screen").height, backgroundColor: "blue"}}></View>
```

Answer (score 4):

try using expo-navigation-bar

```
import * as NavigationBar from "expo-navigation-bar";

NavigationBar.setPositionAsync("absolute");
NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("#ffffff01");
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76165314/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works perfectly for me, actually a really good answer. The part I was missing was setting position absolute - such an obvious thing now I think about it, but I'd just not realised it was possible to do in that way. Man, I've been bashing my head against this problem for *literal weeks*